# How to calculate R-square value for the exponential and power trendline types

Tags: excel, regression, linear-regression, spreadsheet, trendline

Tried to calculate the R-squared value for the exponential and power trendline type using the following equation.

```
   R² = ∑(ȳ - ŷ)² / ∑(y - ȳ)²
```

Here ȳ is the mean value of y and ŷ is the regression equation, here ŷ for
exponential is `y = ae^xb` and for power is `y = ax^b`
Here a = intercept and b = slope.

I have implemented the following code snippet logic to achieve the R squared value

```
  List<int> xValue = <int>[1,2,3,4,5];
List<int> yValue = <int>[2,4,5,4,5];
int sumOfX = 0,sumOfY = 0,sumOfXY = 0, sumOfXSquare = 0, sumOfYSquare = 0;
double slope = 0.5204, intercept = 2.3133;
for(int i = 0; i < xValue.length; i++){
    sumOfX += xValue[i];
    sumOfY += yValue[i];
    sumOfXY += xValue[i] * yValue[i];
    sumOfXSquare += math.pow(xValue[i], 2).toInt();
    sumOfYSquare += math.pow(yValue[i], 2).toInt();
 }
double yMean = sumOfY/yValue.length;
// value of ∑(y - ȳ)²
double ssTol = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < yValue.length; j++){
  ssTol += math.pow((yValue[j] - yMean),2);
 }
// value of ∑(ȳ - ŷ)²
double ssReg = 0;
for(int k = 0; k < yValue.length; k++){
  ssReg += math.pow(((intercept * math.pow(xValue[k], slope)) -yMean), 2).toDouble();
 }
print(ssReg/ssTol);
```

I want the R-squared value like below.

[image]

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You may get more help if you add a tag for the code-snippet language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The correct equation for Rsq is [image] Also, in the most current version of Excel, the Rsquared for your dataset is .7704 not .6782.

[image]

Additionally, Rsquared is only valid for linear regression Models. See [Cross Validated Explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359906/is-r-squared-truly-an-invalid-metric-for-non-linear-models)

However, the power equation can be converted to linear. The Power regression model is in the form ...

y=ax<sup>B</sup>

Take the log of both sides

ln(y) = ln(a) + b*ln(x)

This model can now be fit with linear regression. You might think that the ln(x) part would make linear regression inappropriate, however, linear regression means that it is linear in parameters. [See this link for more information](http://r-statistics.co/Assumptions-of-Linear-Regression.html)

With this form, it is now possible to fit the regression line with linear regression and use the equation for R Squared.

Start by taking the log of both x and y.
[image: Natural log of both sides]

Fit a linear model to the new dataset. Note the Rsq is .7704 as it was above.

[image: Linear Fit]

Recall that our power model is in the form y=ax<sup>B</sup>

B = .5204 (coefficient for X in linear model)

**Reason**: we took the log of x<sup>B</sup> which results in B*ln(X).

a = e<sup>.8387</sup> = 2.3133

**Reason**: we took the log of a which results in ln(a). The ln(a) = .8387. To get "a" we calculate e<sup>ln(a)</sup> = a.

Finally, follow the equation above, to calculate Rsq. Here are some intermediate results to check against your code.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the R2 from the chart by the method suggested by [Bas Verlaat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780921/16125139)

If you want to calculate youself, you may use either the following formula (but there is a difference with the one provided in the chart)

```
=CORREL(A2:A6,C2:C6)^2
```

```
=RSQ(A2:A6,C2:C6)
```

Comment: Hi @idfurw this is fine, but I need mathematical steps to achieve the R square calculation.